# metabase as service with oracle database

Tags: oracle, centos, metabase

I tried [Install Metabase as service](https://www.michaelcho.me/article/running-metabase-locally-as-a-service)tutorial for Metabase Setup on CENTOS. Though i want to run metabase with oracle.

```
[bkmetabase@BK01 MetaBase]$ pwd
/home/bkmetabase/MetaBase

[bkmetabase@BK01 MetaBase]$ ll
total 119488
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bkmetabase bkmetabase      3975 Jun  6 07:52 logger_metabase.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bkmetabase bkmetabase   7503872 Jun  6 07:52 metabase.db.mv.db
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bkmetabase bkmetabase       187 May 27 12:12 metabase.db.trace.db
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bkmetabase bkmetabase 114839203 May 20 13:10 metabase.jar
drwxrwxr-x 2 bkmetabase bkmetabase      4096 May 27 12:05 plugins

[bkmetabase@BK01 MetaBase]$ cd plugins/
[bkmetabase@BK01 MetaBase]$ ll
total 3320
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bkmetabase bkmetabase 3397734 May  5 17:13 ojdbc7.jar
```

> Currently to run as process i am running like below

```
~/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java -jar metabase.jar &> logger_metabase.log &
```

How can we run it as background service with oracle as database?